# Create a new user with limited access to internal user calendars

Tags: google-calendar, google-workspace

We are using Google Apps with Gmail and Calendar. The default settings for calendar visibility is set to shared, all internal users can see each other.

**The task is to create a new user with limited access to other internal user calendars,** the new user need to be able to see details about bookings/events only for a few specific calendars.

This is possible if I change the default visibility behavior so you always have to ask for permission to see any other calendar. But with a few hundred users who should have access to each other, this is not a valid solution.